# Putting session value in a varrible in PHP

Tags: php

I want to store a value from a session in a variable to work on in the current script. However when i run;

```
$from = $_SESSION['userid'];
echo '$from';
```

$from seems to be blank. When i run echo '$_SESSION['userid']'; it returns the correct value

Answer (score 6):

Take out the quotes or change it to double quotes

```
echo $from;
```

Answer (score 1):

When using single quotes variables aren't expanded.  See the [strings documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) for more on this.

You could either do:

```
echo $from;
```

or

```
echo "$from";
```

---

Assuming your id is an integer the code would be more secure this way:

```
$from = intval($_SESSION['userid']);
echo $from;
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$from = $_SESSION['userid']; 
echo $from;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo $from;
```

You don't need quotes around variables to echo. IMHO it's bad practice.

Comment: Use 4 spaces at the beginning of a line to format it as `code`.